# Web Page Not Available error on Release mode in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, dart, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I am using `url_launcher` package to open a Hyper Link when I press a button.

**The problem is that in Debug Mode it works fine and shows the webpage while in Release Mode, it shows that the page is not found error.**

I have added the internet permission on `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
in the following path `android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Like the following:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gtu_marks">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
             the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
             to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

For hyper link my code is:

```
Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 10),
   height: 60,
   width: 60,
   // color: Colors.white,
   child: IconButton(
       onPressed: () {
           launchUrlString("https://github.com/dhruv061");
       },
       icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/Github_Icone.png")
   ),
),
```

The that I am getting:

[image: Error Photo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working in the `Release Mode` because you are adding the permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` that is located inside the `profile` folder, which is related to the `Profile Mode` not `Release Mode`.

To fix the problem, add the Internet Permission to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file that is located in the `main` folder in the following path:

```
android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```